# Adding single Angular-4 component multiple times inside HTML page

Tags: javascript, jquery, angular, aem

We are developing an application in Adobe AEM using angular 4. 
Due to our tool limitation we are not able to add a component inside another component by using ng-selector (parent-child structure).
So currently we are creating the parent Component in HTML and including the Angular components inside by using AEM(tool) feature.

In one of the scenario we need to add a single component multiple times in the HTML page but then we are not able to target the each component to show/hide.

For example.

Template in Component1 :

```
<div *ngif="dynamicvalue">
  <div>show</div>
</div>
```

My HTMl will look like below.

```
<div *ngif="dynamicvalue">  <!-- Component1 added for the 1st time-->
  <div>show</div>
</div>
<div *ngif="dynamicvalue">  <!-- Component1 added for the 2nd time-->
  <div>show</div>
</div>
<div *ngif="dynamicvalue">  <!-- Component1 added for the 3rd time-->
  <div>show</div>
</div>
```

In the above scenario :

1.How can I target only the Component1 added at the 1st position to show/hide?

2.How can I target Component1 added at 1st & 2nd position to show/hide?

Comment: When you say HTML, do you mean an angular html template?

Have you tried using a template reference variable? (https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#ref-vars)

Comment: @VictorNoël - We are using Observable to set the value of "dynamicvalue", could you help us with an example ?

Comment: Wrong architectural approach. Unless you render Angular server side, you should initialise the Angular application in the client, and avoid mixing client- and server side templates. Render the data as JSON into the page and let the application bootstrap itself in the client.